# Cocos2d-x Shaky, Liquid , Wave effect weird behaviour with android

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

I am trying to use the effects like shaky on Sprites and Wave which I guess are heavy process. When I apply this on the sprites they work properly but after If I pause my game and then resume.

Background becomes black and I can not see my bg anymore

Why is this happening I really have no idea ? It happens only when I use these effects

Is there anything I need to take care of after applying this effects on the sprite.

I am not sure is it android bug or my mistake ?

Comment: It only happens onto these effects, it is a known issue on cocos2d-x and I guess it caused by a OpenGL Context lost. it is likely to be fixed in the latest or future version ( not tested yet) sometimes you need wait a while before all the texture comes back coz reloading resources really takes a long time.

Comment: @m.ding : Thanks for d news !!! any alternative that I can look for wave or shaky ? I guess shaky I can do by moving random x and y ..what about wave kind of stuff

Comment: usually 9:00 - 5:30 (AEST/AEDT, currently is AEDT), or you can contact me by email.

Comment: @m.ding Thanks .... may i get your email Id ?